# phpmyadmin using WAMP connection very slow on Windows 8

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

The following is produced by the devel module in Drupal 7. I am running a local version of my site on my Windows 8 machine.

> Executed 787 queries in 391.79 ms.  Page execution time was 5250.65
>   ms.  Memory used at:  devel_boot()=6.12 MB,  devel_shutdown()=101.55
>   MB,  PHP peak=102.75 MB.

I cannot fathom what's causing the huge execution time.

Any tips much appreciated

I have done all suggested in [this post](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,91602)

Lee

Comment: Start cutting out large chunks of code and see how you execution time changes?

Comment: Yep - As Sarah says, the best thing to do would be to strip it down to a point it goes quicker, then start reintroducing the code, so as to pin-point what's causing the slow-down.

Comment: i cleaned out a lot of nodes, there were approx 20k in total. this seems to have speeded it up a bit. I have now created an Ubuntu Server using Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ip address instead of localhost in your connection

So where you see

```
$server = "localhost"
```

use

```
$server = "127.0.0.1"
```